# When I define a variable as the split of an item, can't I just print the variable?

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I don't get this one part.
So this is the code

```
list = []
story = urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/txt')
for line in story:
    x = line.split()
    for word in x:
        list.append(word)
```

I'm wondering why I can't just do `list.append(x)` after I defined `x = line.split()`?

Since I already broke each individual line into a list of words and defined the list as `x`, why can't I just append that to the blank list I created but instead have to take define `word` as each item in the list `x` then append it?

Comment: Well, you can, but that'll do something different. If that different thing is the thing you want to do, then go ahead.

Comment: There's also `extend`.

Comment: This is probably worth just trying out. Add a `print(list)` statement at the end, and see what the output is in both cases.

Comment: `x = line.split()` is a list. You can append a list to a list, but it appears you wish to append each element of a list to a list. In this case, you may wish to use the more convenient `list+=x` or, equivalently `list = list+x`. This `+` operator just concatenates two lists together into one. One other point for your specific example: it's generally undesirable to use the word `list` for your own custom list, since `list` is a built-in sequence type.

Comment: An hint: dont use list  as name of a list it is the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

`for line in story`. Breaks the file into every row within it.

`x = line.split()`. Breaks the particular row into its columns. This is an example of a 2x2 dimensional array